# Rubber band domains

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

"Rubber band" domains are defined below.

(i) Is this class of domains already named?
If so, what is the name?

(ii) What results about rubber
band domains are known/published?

This class of domains seems to be relevant
to the "Lion and Man" pursuit problem.

The crucial condition in the following
definition is (d).

**Definition**. A set $D$ will be called a *rubber
band domain* if it satisfies the following
conditions.

(i) $D$ is an open bounded connected subset
of $\mathbb R^3$. Its boundary is smooth.

(ii) "Every rubber band is contractible
to a point." More precisely, if K is
a subset of $D$, it is homeomorphic to
the unit circle $U$ and has a finite
length (i.e., $K$ is a rectifiable Jordan curve) 
then there exists a continuous function $M(x,t)$ 
defined on  $U \times [0,1]$ such that

(a) for every $t \in [0,1)$, $M(x,t)$ is
a homeomorphism between $U$ and its range

(b) the range of $M(x,1$) is a single point in $D$

(c) for any $t \in [0,1]$, the range of $M(x, t)$
is a rectifiable Jordan curve

(d) if $s < t$ and $s,t$ belong to $[0,1]$
then the length of the range of $M(x,s)$
is not smaller than the length
of the range of $M(x,t)$.

Comment: Why the "algebraic geometry" tag?

Comment: Any reason you've restricted to subsets of $\mathbb R^3$? It seems the Riemannian manifolds $M$ such that any loop in $M$ is connected to a trivial loop by a path on which the arc-length function is monotonic more or less captures what you're after. No?

Comment: So conditions (a-c) just guarantees that $D$ is simply connected. Condition (d) is similar, but stronger, than the requirement that there are no locally length minimizing geodesics. (The sphere is a rubberband domain, the sphere without the south pole is not.) I wonder if Dick Palais will be able to say more?

Answer (score 1):

Any convex polyhedron is a rubber-band domain if you drop the requirement that $D$ is open.

To see this, take a loop, and push it around until it becomes a geodesic. Now translate the entire loop in a direction orthogonal to the loop, keeping the length of the loop constant, until it bumps into a vertex. It won't unexpectedly intersect itself while you are doing this. Now if you push a part of the loop past that vertex, the loop decreases in length since the polyhedron is convex. Now push it around again until it becomes a geodesic, and repeat. There are only finitely many possible lengths for a closed geodesic that doesn't intersect itself, so this process eventually finishes.

More generally, I think any convex surface should be a rubber band domain.

**Edit:** I was thinking about this problem today, and it finally hit me!

If $D$ is the *complement* of an object (intersected with a large ball containing the surface), then this is exactly the condition that there is no knot that can't be slipped off the object. So by the answers to the question I posed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8091/is-it-possible-to-capture-a-sphere-in-a-knot), we have the results that:

(1) The complement of a ball (intersected with the interior of a larger ball) is a rubber band domain.

(2) The complement of an equilateral triangle (intersected with the interior of a large ball) is not a rubber band domain.