# Hanging a ball with string

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, classical-mechanics

> What is the shortest length of string that suffices to hang
>   a unit-radius ball $B$?

This question is related to [an earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8091/is-it-possible-to-capture-a-sphere-in-a-knot), but I think different.

1. Assume that the ball is frictionless.
   Perhaps $B$ is a billiard ball, and the string is nylon thread.
2. Start under the restriction that you are not permitted to cut
   the string.
3. But you may tie knots, whose total length $\epsilon$ is negligible
   (or we can take the infimum of all lengths).
4. Let $h$ be the distance from the topmost hanging point to the north
   pole of $B$.

Here is a possible solution of length $L = 3\pi + h$.

[image: Ball Hanging]

The green portion is $h$.
The blue forms one loop from north pole $N$ through south pole $S$
and back up to $N$, at which point it is tied and then
descends again to tie at $S$. I am a bit uncertain if this $120^\circ$ partitioning could
be maintained without friction.
Just one great circle of length $2\pi$ would leave hemispheres exposed, allowing the
ball to fall out under the slightest perturbation.

Variations are obtained by altering the assumptions above.
Suppose there is friction $\mu$.  Perhaps $B$ is a tennis ball,
and the string is twine.
Maybe then a type of spiral shorter than $3\pi$ would work?
Allowing cutting of the string may help.
Maybe then one could fashion a bird's nest into which $B$
nestles, achieving a length closer to $L = 2\pi + h$?
Tying a knot above the north pole of $B$ could conceivably help,
in which case the length of $h$ might play a role.

Any ideas would be welcomed, including sharpenings of the problem specification.
I am especially interested to hear of a provably optimal solution
under any variation.

**Addendum (28Oct10)**. Here is a depiction of Scott's suggestion in the comments:

[image: Ball Triangle]

**Addendum (10Feb11)**. Martin Demaine at MIT contacted me to inform me that this
question was asked and answered long ago: H.T. Croft wrote a paper, "A Net to Hold a Sphere,"
*J. London Math. Soc.*, 39, (1964) pp.1-4. ([PDF here](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-39/1/1.full.pdf).)  He credits the problem and solution
to A.S. Besicovitch in a paper from 1957, same title, *Math. Gaz.* XLI, pp. 106-7.  Here is Croft's first sentence:

> Besicovitch `[1]` has shown: if a net of inextensible string encloses a sphere of unit radius
>   in such a way that the sphere cannot slip out, then the length of the string is strictly greater
>   than $3 \pi$, and this is false with any greater constant replacing $3 \pi$.

This result accords with the answers below, by Scott and drvitek.

Comment: Your configuration is metastable, just like a loop: you can free the ball by exerting negligible energy to move one of the semicircles around.  However if you make an arbitrarily small triangle on the bottom, then it becomes stable.

Comment: @Scott: Thanks for the term _metastable_, which is quite apropos here! 

Comment: Hmm.  According to Wikipedia, I should use "unstably equilibrated" instead of "metastable", since the latter term requires energy input that is small but bounded away from zero.

Comment: If I had twine with several threads, I would take the middle of a length of twine of about 2*pi, and separate the threads to form a small hammock.  I would then use some twine to put a knot in between to keep the two sections from coming together. The ball would then rest in a very tiny hammock.  Perhaps some idealization of placing a knot in the middle exists.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.10.27

Comment: @Gerhard: Separating the threads of twine is a novel idea! Your small hammock is roughly what I meant by a "bird's nest."

Comment: @Gerhard: It seems like the physics implies that strings can resist tension but not compression.  I don't think you could make a "separating knot" with this setup.

Comment: A related later question: [Hanging a cube with string](https://mathoverflow.net/q/361573/6094).

Answer (score 7):

There is another stable solution of total length $3\pi + h + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.  We take a circle of constant latitude $\delta < 0$ (sufficiently small) and then connect this circle to the north pole via two diametrically opposed strings.  This is then clearly stable.  Furthermore this is equivalent to your solution (plus Scott Carnahan's epsilon-modification).

However, there is in fact a stable solution of total string-length $2\pi+h+\epsilon$.  We simply take the almost-equatorial circle in the last solution and drag it to the south pole, so that we have a small circle there along with two diametrically opposed support strings connecting it to the north pole.  This solution is (barely) stable, although physically it is not exactly easy to implement (a very small but non-negligible disturbance will suffice to remove the ball).

The reason for the two answers: this was my thought process in action.

**EDIT**: Please disregard the above; both of these solutions are unstable.

In fact Scott's example is part of a general class of solutions of total length $3\pi+h+\epsilon.$  Take any two diametrically opposite points, and draw a small spherical triangle containing one of the points.  Connect all six possible edges between the four points by geodesics, and finally rotate the arrangement so that one of the strings passes through the north pole.

Here is a short proof that any stable configuration must have at least four points where three or more strings meet.  If there are three or less points, there is a hemisphere $H$ which contains all of the points.  Take the complement $H^C$ of this hemisphere; we can remove any strings in $H^C$ because they cannot be geodesics.  As $H^C$ doesn't contain the north pole, the sphere can fall out.

Note that if any strings are not geodesics between junctions, we can ignore the strings.

Here is a short proof (that is not quite rigorous) that could provide a lower bound.  Suppose there is not a loop (that is, a set of points connected by geodesics) that is completely contained in the southern hemisphere.  Then we may drag any points in the southern hemisphere into the northern hemisphere.  (This statement is the part I can't make completely rigorous.)  So the sphere must be unstable.  Now if we have a loop in the southern hemisphere, there must be at least two strings meeting at the north pole, as otherwise we could simply slide all of the string off one side of the sphere.

So we must have a loop in the southern hemisphere and (not necessarily direct) connections from at least two of these points to the north pole.  I can't figure out how to work a good lower bound from here.

Comment: If you only have two support strings, there is a rotation around the axis joining the junctions that frees the ball with negligible energy input.

Comment: Scott - I don't quite get what you're saying.  Which two junctions?

Comment: Your two support strings join a circle at two points that are below the equator, so the line between those two points passes below the center of the ball.  You can rotate the circle together with the ball around that line, and the height of the center of the ball will decrease monotonically.

Comment: @drvitek: I think he means the line through the points where the support strings from $N$ meet the small circle near $S$...?

Comment: Alternatively, you can slip one half of the constant-latitude circle of string around the bottom of the ball to join the other half.  This yields a non-equilibrium configuration.

Comment: Ack!  So that means both of my solutions are wrong!

Comment: @drvitek: Still clever, and useful to explore the options and constraints. And perhaps it works under different assumptions.

Comment: With friction the moves suggested by Scott require energy, so drvitek's solution would be valid for that extension of the problem.

Comment: You can fix this by putting a second small loop just under the north pole, which prevents the ball from slipping out when tilted.

Comment: I think Ryan's solution works and gives the $2\pi+h+\epsilon$ that drvitek originally claimed.

Comment: I would say that $2\pi$ is the theoretical minimum, since it takes that much just to do a great circle.  If you use less than that, then some complete hemisphere is on one side of your string.

Comment: @Louigi: I am not so sure myself, now.  Scott's last objection seems valid still: you can push half of both loops into the same hemisphere and the sphere falls out again.  Not sure how to prevent that.

Comment: (Edit: added solution that actually works, distinct from Scott's.)